# Why is my query slower when I use the index I made for it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have the following table, made with EntityFramework 6.1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MachineryReading] (
    [Id]                 INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Location]           [sys].[geometry] NULL,
    [Latitude]           FLOAT (53)       NOT NULL,
    [Longitude]          FLOAT (53)       NOT NULL,
    [Altitude]           FLOAT (53)       NULL,
    [Odometer]           INT              NULL,
    [Speed]              FLOAT (53)       NULL,
    [BatteryLevel]       INT              NULL,
    [PinFlags]           BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [DateRecorded]       DATETIME         NOT NULL,
    [DateReceived]       DATETIME         NOT NULL,
    [Satellites]         INT              NOT NULL,
    [HDOP]               FLOAT (53)       NOT NULL,
    [MachineryId]        INT              NOT NULL,
    [TrackerId]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [ReportType]         NVARCHAR (1)     NULL,
    [FixStatus]          INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [AlarmStatus]        INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [OperationalSeconds] INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.MachineryReading] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MachineryReading_dbo.Machinery_MachineryId] FOREIGN KEY ([MachineryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Machinery] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MachineryReading_dbo.Tracker_TrackerId] FOREIGN KEY ([TrackerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tracker] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MachineryId]
    ON [dbo].[MachineryReading]([MachineryId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TrackerId]
    ON [dbo].[MachineryReading]([TrackerId] ASC);
```

Thats a lot of information, and our most common (and slowest) query only uses a subset of it:

```
SELECT TOP 1 OperationalSeconds
  FROM MachineryReading
  WHERE MachineryId = @id
    AND DateRecorded > @start
    AND DateRecorded < @end
    AND OperationalSeconds <> 0
```

The table stores a few million rows, recorded from about 2012 onwards, although our code is set to begin some searches from 2000. It was running pretty slowly, so one of the guys I work with partitioned the table based on DateRecorded:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PartitionSchemeMonthRange NEXT USED [Primary]
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitionFunctionMonthRange]() SPLIT RANGE(N'2016-01-01T00:00:00.000') 

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PartitionSchemeMonthRange NEXT USED [Primary]
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitionFunctionMonthRange]() SPLIT RANGE(N'2016-02-01T00:00:00.000') 
...

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_dbo.MachineryReadingPs] ON MachineryReading(DateRecorded, Id) ON PartitionSchemeMonthRange(DateRecorded)
```

However, the query above is still running pretty slowly. So on top of that, I made another index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MachineryId_DateRecorded]
    ON [dbo].[MachineryReading]([DateRecorded] ASC, [MachineryId] ASC)
    INCLUDE([OperationalSeconds], [FixStatus]);
```

Executing that query again, the execution plan shows it completely ignoring the index I just made, instead opting for Constant Scan, and Index Seek on IX_MachineryId. This works pretty quickly for a small date range, but is terrible for getting the total operational hours.

Ok, I can deal with that: `WITH(INDEX(IX_MachineryId_DateRecorded))`.

Nope. It actually runs significantly *slower*, when using the index I made specifically for that query! What gives? What can I do better?

Comment: Why did you put DateRecorded before MachineryId in the index? I would've done it the other way around

Comment: Try an index on `(MachineryID, DateRecorded)`.  Having it that order should make it much more beneficial to the optimiser.  *(The order you used puts everything in time order.  The suggested order puts everything in machine order.)*

Comment: That's a typo by me - I named it IX_MachineryId_DateRecorded, it is supposed to be in that order. That could explain a lot...

Comment: Also, I doubt it matters, but you can try using BETWEEN instead of < or > for the dates. At least it might improve readability a little bit

Comment: We're not talking about the NAME of the index.  We're talking about the order of the columns you're indexing.  In your example everything is ordered by datetime first, and then records with the same datetime are ordered by machine.  That's a horrible order for your query.  Indexing those two fields the other way round structures the data Much more effectively for your needs.

Comment: I know. I name the index in the same order as I write the columns. My point was that I wrote the name in the right order, but wrote the columns in the wrong order. I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: Was it a typo in your question, or a typo on your actual system?  Do you still have performance issues with the correct index and the exact query in your question?  If so, please provide full execution plans for us to look at (with and without your index hint).

Comment: It was a typo in my migration script, in the actual system :O. I'm just updating it now to see if it fixes the problem, it takes about 7 minutes to recreate though. Will let you know soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have DateRecorded before MachineryId in your indexes. Reverse these for a more efficient index.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes someone else to see your mistakes

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Did that actually end up fixing the issue? How big of a difference did it make?

Comment: It has made a phenomenal difference. For some reason, I still have to force it with `WITH(INDEX(...`, but it is much faster when I do that. Gone from minutes to ~1 second